# Linq to Sql Table Design

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I am trying to implement a database connection with linq to sql. I made a class **User** and a class **License** which are looking like this:

User:

```
[Table(Name = "User")]
public class User {

    [Column(Name = "UserID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "EMail", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Password", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "JoinedDate", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "PaymentMethodID", CanBeNull = true)]
    public int PaymentMethodID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Address", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "PostalCode", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Town", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

License:

```
[Table(Name = "License")]
public class License {

    [Column(Name = "LicenseID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int LicenseID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "CPUID")]
    public string CPUID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "LicenseTypeID")]
    public int LicenseTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

Every **User** can have multiple **License**s. Normally I would add a Field inside **License** **UserID**. But is there a way to add a **List** to **User**? And if so, how do I have to design the **User Table**?

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a licence has to be assigned to a user then you need to store that fact somewhere in the database. The usual way to do this is to add a UserId property to the licence. This will generate a list of licences on the user record.

You can add a list of licenses manually, but you still need to populate that list with data.

Another alternative is to have a User/Licence table that maps the user to the licence. This will add an indirect reference from the user to the licence via the mapping table.

If you want to add more properties to the user class that aren't stored in the database then you can create a partial class in the same namespace:

```
public partial class User
{
    public List<Licence> Licences { get; set; }
}
```

However, you'll need to write the code necessary to populate this list when loading your user records.

Comment: As i mentioned i would do this normally, but is there a way to work with a List?

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I'm not sure I follow - if a licence has to be assigned to a user then you need to store that fact somewhere in the database - either as a column on the license table itself or in a separate mapping table.

Comment: Yes, that's what I usually do when designing a database.
But is there a way to add a List<License> to the User class, without adding a Column UserID to the License Class?

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin - yes there is - but where is the data going to be stored?

Comment: Alright, so there is no way to make something like
`[Column(Name = "Licenses")]
public List<Licence> Licences { get; set; }` ?

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin - that's not going to work as the user table doesn't have a column called "Licences". I'm beginning to think that you're trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: That could be possible. Alright, i will do that with creating a column UserID inside License.
Thanks for your help